# Calling function on parent scope from nginclude

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am using nginclude to change a partial view, and inside the partial view, I have a controller, and inside that controller, I want to call a function from the parent scope that changes the a variable. How do I do that?

Comment: I think I have solved my problem now. The prototypal chain was not working if I use "var vm = this", and define the function I want to call on vm. If I define it on $scope, it works. Why is that?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `$broadcast`

Parent controller:

```
$scope.$broadcast("myEvent");
```

Child controller:

```
$scope.$on("myEvent", function() {
    console.log("Running my event");
});
```